# Auto populate custom fields by post date

Tags: posts, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have an old blog with lots of posts,

I created 2 new custom fields "Year" and "Month" using ACF.

I would like to auto populate them from the post date after post save/update, is this possible ?

Is there a function I can run to do this to all my old posts as well ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this with a nice function, now the only thing left to do is to find a way to update all of the blog posts. doing this by hand will be really bad

here is the code that I used

add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  } else {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }

$mydata = get_the_time('Y'); // Do something with $mydata 
  $mymonth = get_the_time('F');

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'year_', $mydata );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'month', $mymonth );
}